# Why is the Ackermann function related to the amortized complexity of union-find algorithm used for disjoint sets?

Tags: set, complexity-theory, ackermann

Can anybody give me an intuitive explanation of why the Ackermann function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function is related to the amortized complexity of union-find algorithm used for disjoint sets http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure?

The analysis in Tarjan's data structure book isn't very intuitive.

I also looked it up in Introduction to Algorithms, but it also seems too rigorous and non-intuitive.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CrisStringfellow How should I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Applied to Disjoint-set forests

from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)

> (about find and union) These two
>   techniques complement each other;
>   applied together, the amortized time
>   per operation is only O(α(n)), where
>   α(n) is the inverse of the function
>   f(n) = A(n,n), and A is the extremely
>   quickly-growing Ackermann function.
>   Since α(n) is the inverse of this
>   function, α(n) is less than 5 for all
>   remotely practical values of n. Thus,
>   the amortized running time per
>   operation is effectively a small
>   constant.

#### So why Ackerman?

from [Kruskal algoritm](http://www.mec.ac.in/resources/notes/notes/ds/kruskul.htm)

> #### The Function lg*n
>
> Note that lg*n is a very slow growing
>   function, much slower than lg n.  In
>   fact is slower than lg lg n, or any
>   finite composition of lg n.  It is the
>   inverse of the function f(n) = 2
>   ^2^2^…^2, n times.  For n >=  5, f(n)
>   is greater than the number of atoms in
>   the universe.  Hence for all intents
>   and purposes, the inverse of f(n) for
>   any real life value of n, is constant.
>   From an engineer’s point of view,
>   Kruskal’s algorithm runs in O(e). 
>   Note of course that from a
>   theoretician’s point of view, a true
>   result of O(e) would still be a
>   significant breakthrough.  **The whole
>   picture is not complete because the
>   actual best result shows that lg*n can
>   be replaced by the inverse of A(p,n)
>   where A is Ackermann’s function, a
>   function that grows explosively.  The
>   inverse of Ackermann’s function is
>   related to lg*n, and is a nicer
>   result, but the proof is even
>   harder.**

Comment: I'm not sure if this provides me with any insight on this.

Comment: Log function is very used in amortization calculations. As far as I understand, Ackerman function is used as a substitute for log due its exponential growth and behavior similarities with it; at least in this case. anyway, I'd suggest you to give a glance to the Krustal's link. hope it helps you someway :)

Comment: In complexity analysis, its usually the inverse of the Ackermann function that is used.  This post says "α(V) = O(lg V) is a common abuse of notation". 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44354922/why-is-the-inverse-ackermann-function-used-to-describe-complexity-of-kruskals-a